# html_simple_dom - Call to a member function find() on null

Tags: php, curl, dom

in my project I use newest htmlsimpledom installed via composer. My curl script is logging into external b2b page and returns html. Problem is that i cannot process it with `html_simple_do`m because load function shows null after processing html. Here is my code:

**//html returned via curl looks like this (displayed with dd() - laravel):**

[image]

simple_html_dom:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new \simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb();
}

private function login()
{
    $site1 = $curl->get_data_curl('https://main.b2b.somedomain.pl/pl/user/home', $data); //it's html from image above
    $getData = $this->client->load($site1); // this cause NULL
    $fields = $getData->find("input[id=username]"); // this throw error because null above
}
```

I'm not sure about what causing problem because on my server there is old piece of code where is the same html processed via `html_simple_dom` but with very old version of code like from 2012~ and without object way (using `str_get_html()`)

Many thanks for any help and have a nice day.

UPDATE:
calling `$this->client->load('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');**` also cause null

Answer (score 0):

For future devs with same problem:

change:

```
new \simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb();
```

to:

```
new \simplehtmldom\HtmlDocument();
```